Convergence of the series $\sum_{n}\frac{3^{n}n!}{7 \cdot 10 \cdot 13 \cdots (3n+4)}x^{n}$, $x >0$
Question:
Convergence of the series $\sum_{n}\frac{3^{n}n!}{7 \cdot 10 \cdot 13 \cdots (3n+4)}x^{n}$, $x >0$. I want to know its convergence at $x=1$.
Context:
I have found that the radius of the convergence of the above series is 1 by following means:
$$1 \geq \frac{n!}{\frac{7 \cdot 10 \cdot 13 \cdots  (3n+4)}{3^{n}}} \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ and then raising every term by $\frac{1}{n}$ and then taking limit $n$ tends to $\infty$ followed by sandwich theorem. But I am not able to conclude what happens to the series at $x=1$.
The question has answer here, but it seemed to be non rigorous and didn't help much.

For $x=1$ I would reason that $$\begin{align}
\sum_{n}\frac{3^{n}n!}{7 \cdot 10 \cdot 13 \ldots (3n+4)}&= \sum_{n}\frac{3^{n}n!}{3^n\cdot (1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+\frac43)}\\
&= \sum_{n}\frac{\Gamma(\frac73)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac73)}
.\end{align}$$
Since $$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac73)}\sim cn^{-\frac43},$$
the series converges.
Edit
Let us try prove the same without using $\Gamma$-function. Even more, we will find the value of this sum!
$$\sum_{n}\frac{3^{n}n!}{3^n\cdot (1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+\frac43)} =$$
$$=\sum_{n}\frac{n!}{(1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+\frac43)}.$$
Consider the partial sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{n!}{(1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n+\frac43)}.$$
It actually telescopes to $$3-\frac{4m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}.$$
Or, you can just use induction: $$3-\frac{4m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}+ \frac{m!}{(1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (m+\frac43)} =$$
$$=3- \frac{m!\cdot(-\frac43+4(m+\frac43))}{(0+\frac43)\cdot(1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (m+\frac43)}= $$
$$=3- \frac{4(m+1)!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot(1+\frac43) \cdot (2+\frac43) \cdot \ldots \cdot (m+\frac43)}.$$
Then we have $$\frac{m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}=$$
$$=\frac{m!}{(1+\frac13)\cdot
(2+\frac13)\cdot\ldots\cdot (m+\frac13)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1+\frac1{1\cdot3})\cdot
(1+\frac1{2\cdot3})\cdot\ldots\cdot (1+\frac1{m\cdot3})}\le$$
$$\le\frac{1}{(1+\frac1{m\cdot3})\cdot
(1+\frac1{m\cdot3})\cdot\ldots\cdot (1+\frac1{m\cdot3})}=$$
$$=\frac1{(1+\frac1{3m})^m}= \left(\frac1{(1+\frac1{3m})^{3m}} \right)^{\frac13}\underset{m\to\infty}\longrightarrow e^{-\frac13}.$$
So, we have $$\log\left(\frac{m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}\right)\le 
\log \left(\frac1{(1+\frac1{3m})^{3m}} \right)^{\frac13}.$$
$\sum \log \left(\frac1{(1+\frac1{3m})^{3m}} \right)^{\frac13}$ diverges to $-\infty$ since $\log \left(\frac1{(1+\frac1{3m})^{3m}} \right)^{\frac13}\to-\frac13$. Hence $\sum\log\left(\frac{m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}\right)$ diverges to $-\infty$. And hence the sequence of partial products converges to $0$. Finally, the sequence $3-\frac{4m!}{(0+\frac43)\cdot
(1+\frac43)\cdot\ldots \cdot(m-1+\frac43)}$ converges to $3$.

Thanks for the response. I fixed the link. I am not aware of the Gamma function, so I am not able to comprehend this answer.

Well, I just edited the answer to not use the Gamma function @Debu

My comment asserting that the argument in this answer could be applied to the present question was incorrect (it matters that the constant $\tfrac27$ in that question is $<1,$ unlike $\tfrac43$ in this question); I apologise.
